# What is the correct syntax for adding a custom cookie in Google Analytics?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, security

Google's own site seems to provide conflicting documentation.

I've found at least 4 variations for adding A custom cookie to GA.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=6a452bd09455721a&hl=en

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=4362f4d46e6e723a&hl=en

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/07/segment-your-traffic-with-user-defined.html

Here is the code I currently have embedded in my company's sharepoint site.  I'm beginning to think that this will not work, and that I will have to create an "employee.html" page on my public webserver that I will have to request all employees load once to generate the cookie on their PC's.  My secondary question, is after I setup a employee.html page as the example http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/07/segment-your-traffic-with-user-defined.html here describes, how do I keep all the external traffic from accessing that same page?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20842347-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'visitor-type','employee']);   
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.sc-pa.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>   
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those links talk about setting a custom cookie.  Also, it seems to me that you aren't really needing to set a custom cookie.  It looks like you are just wanting to be able to segment your traffic into different buckets.

You can do this many different ways, one of which you have in your code example: you can set a custom variable with different values, depending on the type of user.

So it would set the same cookie, etc.. and you pass different values in this line of code

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'visitor-type','employee']);
```

Then in your reports you can setup filters based off of custom variable 1, or look at the custom variable reports directory, or use custom variable 1 as a metric in your reports.

Comment: From http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/07/segment-your-traffic-with-user-defined.html `Notice the line in bold that includes _setVar. When this is present on a page within the Google Analytics Tracking Code, an additional cookie (called the __utmv cookie) gets set on a visitor’s computer, with its sole purpose being to identify the visitor by the label (or value) that you used in the code. If you take a look at the code example above, you will see that I used the term “customers,“ the label that I want to appear in the User Defined report.`

Comment: right, but you aren't changing the cookie name, just the value. And it is the value that is used to segment.  And there are lots of other ways to segment.  The point being, there's no need to use separate cookies for things.

Comment: @CrayonViolent: I appreciate your response.  I think you are getting into semantics.  What I called a separate cookie you appear to be calling a cookie value.  I'm no cookie expert (I never wanted to change the cookie name), I just want to confirm the correct syntax.  each of those links in my OP have different syntax.

Comment: Is it `pageTracker._setVar(”employees”); ` or `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Section', 'Life & Style', 3]);` or `_gaq._setVar('employees')`

Comment: okay yes, there are different syntaxes because there are different styles/versions of GA code floating around.  Based on the code you provided in your question, you are using the new async version.  So you need to use this syntax: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar which is what you have in your code already

Comment: @CrayonViolent: Thanks, now did you understand my second concern?  If I create this 'employee.html' page, like in the analytics.blogspot example how do I block it so that only employees can access it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need to create a separate page to put this code on? Why can't you just set it on one of your (presumably) existing pages that only your employees can access? Because you have to have the GA code on every page you want to track

Comment: I'm picturing an email 'please click the following link http://www.sc-pa.com/employeetracker.html', and yes I want only employees to access this page, but obviously if it is on our public server I have to know how to ask our network team to block it to external traffic, which I do not know how to ask them that.

Comment: do you have GA code on other pages that only the employees can view? Just have them to put this page in the same place.  I can't really be more specific than that since I don't really know how things are setup for you

Comment: no, it is a public website, everyone can access all pages. GA is working great, all setup and returning data. but if I add `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'visitor-type','employee']);` to say default.asp then every vistor to the site would be considered an employee. right? I have to have a public page that only employees can access?

Comment: well..yes and no. If your ultimate goal is to see which users are employees and which users are not, then yes, you will have to somehow determine when/where to trigger that code. How that is accomplished would really be up to your IT dept to figure out, not you ( unless you ARE part of the IT dept :) ).  But fyi that's not going to be an easy task, unless your employees all work in an office and are on your office's network and then IT can basically say "okay, user is on this IP address, so count them as an employee".

Comment: Or if your site requires people to login, and employees have a special login/account, then IT can determine from that, but it won't work until user is actually logged in and can be identified as such.